# Нужна ли точка после кавычек при цитировании чужих слов?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, цитирование

*Они сделали перерыв после того, как Андрей сказал: «Останавливаемся!». Игорь затормозил у обочины и заглушил мотор.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае точка не нужна, поскольку слово в кавычках является отдельным предложением, которое заканчивается на воскл. знак.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Точка не нужна.

> **В конце фразы после закрывающих цитату кавычек:**
> <...>
> в) не ставят никаких знаков, если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак, а заключенная в кавычки цитата является самостоятельным предложением (таковы, как правило, все цитаты после двоеточия, отделяющего их от предшествующих им слов цитирующего):
>
> *Глава заканчивается словами: «Прощай, философия, прощай, молодость, прощай, Германия!»*

Источник: [**Грамота.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-kav1).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.